# Perl's worker don't process connections, waiting on a futex

Tags: perl, fastcgi, futex

We have 10 workers processing user's connections. Workers are implemented in Perl, using `FCGI` and `FCGI::ProcManager`.

Sometimes, one worker stop processing of connections. Strace displays:

```
futex(0x7fa9ebde0e80, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL
```

That is it sleep, waiting on a futex.

The worker never returns from waiting.

If we kill this worker with

```
kill -9
```

then its parent reap it. Return code equal 9.

Our project is highload. This issue appears very rarely.

Comment: The worker never returns from waiting.

Comment: Okay, and you want to know from us why?? or How to fix it or what? The question is still not clear ..

Comment: I want to know why this happen. And how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [futex man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/futex):

> This system call is typically used to implement the contended case of a lock in shared memory, as described in futex(7)

So my first question: is your Perl script using "Perl Threads" and are you having contention on a shared memory variable?

Comment: I don't use any "Perl Threads" explicitly. I don't use any shared memory variables explicitly. May be, one of standart modules use them.